# Keeping only the unique elements in an array Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, unique

I have an array that contains the following:

```
67A 
257B 
67C 
257D
```

I want to keep only the unique numbers, meaning I want my array to contain 67A and 257B. How would I do this in a Bash script?

Comment: Why the rest two elements are not unique? All of them are different from each other. How are you applying the "unique" concept in your problem, please add more information.

Comment: If this somehow manages to get reopened, I have a pure bash solution.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc I know it doesn't matter much now, but these codes are actually a part of a protein. The letters correspond to the chain and the numbers correspond to the amino acid. So 67A and 67C are the same and 257B and 257D are the same. I was able to get the unique numbers before, but the way I was doing it caused the letters to be swapped so I ended up with 67B and 257A which corresponds to an entirely different amino acid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create a new array with the unique numbered values which will take the first of each numeric prefix found. Say your values are in the indexed-array `array`. You could do:

```
new_array=( $(printf "%s\n" ${array[@]} | sort -n -u) )
```

Above you are just using the *command-substitution* of `printf` (used to output each element on a separate line) piped to `sort -n -u` (which sorts numerically unique). You use the results to populate `new_array`.

Now `new_array` would contain:

```
67A
257B
```

Comment: You are welcome -- good luck with your scripting!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, that's simple, sober and cool answer cheers thank you for sharing you ROCK :)

Comment: Every once it a while I get something right (kinda like a blind squirrel finds a nut -- every once in a while `:)`